# what does first() function do

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I had that problem below:

[image]

expression value of my column was `Fields!tranche.Value`, when I change it to `first(Fields!tranche.Value)` then the problem resolved and I get what I want:

[image]

but I dont know why, can someone explain to me please.

Comment: You need to provide more information. Are the columns in a column group, is there any row grouping, what does your dataset look like?

Answer (score 0):

The `first` function selects the first value.